# How to use two pickers in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have two pickers in react native with fetch data from API, but when I add another picker from another fetch data API, the EXPO APP crash. I tried to change the name of dataSource but still I have the error. This is my code, Thanks!.

```
  componentDidMount() {

    return fetch('http://address/api/AreaUnidades/obtenerAreas')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
          dataSource: responseJson
        }, function() {
          // In this block you can do something with new state.
        });
      })


      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      }); 

  }


//SELECT CARS
  componentDidMount2() {

    return fetch('http://address/api/InventarioMarchamos/obtenerVehiculos/')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson1) => {
        this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
          dataSource2: responseJson1
        }, function() {
          // In this block you can do something with new state.
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      }); 
  }
```

Code of pickers:

```
<Picker
  selectedValue={this.state.PickerValueHolder}
   onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({PickerValueHolder: itemValue})} >
    { this.state.dataSource.map((item, key)=>(
     <Picker.Item label={item.area} value={item.id_area} key={key} STF = {this.setFirstValue("1")} />)
     )}
</Picker>


<Picker
  selectedValue={this.state.PickerVehiculos}
   onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({PickerVehiculos: itemValue})} >
    { this.state.dataSource.map((item, key)=>(
     <Picker.Item label={item.Placa} value={item.IdUnidad} key={key}  />)
     )}
</Picker>
```

Comment: What do you expect with `componentDidMount2()`? That's not a life cycle method.

Comment: I get the data of the another Picker, sorry I'm new in react native. How i should call that data?

Comment: After putting everything in `componentDidMount` as mentioned above, you'll also need to correct your code in your second picker since you're using `this.state.dataSource` in your second picker as well instead of `this.state.dataSource2`.

Comment: Thank you @azundo!, I did that right but this.state.dataSource is undefined, can you tell me please how I can copy everything in componentDidMount? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to tell without your full component but I imagine you're running into issues with the `isLoading` state as well if you're conditionally rendering based on that.

The code below puts both `fetch` calls in `componentDidMount` (no need to return the value of `fetch` there) and adds an additional `loading` state for the second data source. Finally hook up the second picker to `dataSource2`.

```
class TwoPickers extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      dataSource: [],
      dataSource2: [],
      isLoading: true,
      isLoading2: true,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://address/api/AreaUnidades/obtenerAreas')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        this.setState(
          {
            isLoading: false,
            dataSource: responseJson,
          },
          function() {
            // In this block you can do something with new state.
          }
        );
      })

      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
    fetch('http://address/api/InventarioMarchamos/obtenerVehiculos/')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson1 => {
        this.setState(
          {
            isLoading2: false,
            dataSource2: responseJson1,
          },
          function() {
            // In this block you can do something with new state.
          }
        );
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }
  render() {
    const {isLoading, isLoading2} = this.state;
    if (isLoading || isLoading2) {
      // your loading component
    }
    return (
      <>
        <Picker
          selectedValue={this.state.PickerValueHolder}
           onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({PickerValueHolder: itemValue})} >
            { this.state.dataSource.map((item, key)=>(
             <Picker.Item label={item.area} value={item.id_area} key={key} STF = {this.setFirstValue("1")} />)
             )}
        </Picker>


        <Picker
          selectedValue={this.state.PickerVehiculos}
           onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({PickerVehiculos: itemValue})} >
            { this.state.dataSource.map((item, key)=>(
             <Picker.Item label={item.Placa} value={item.IdUnidad} key={key}  />)
             )}
        </Picker>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```